# UIpopover is presenting user with a 'done' button that I can't get rid of

Tags: iphone, ipad, porting, uipopovercontroller

I'm not sure why this is coming up I am porting my app into an ipad version and moving one of my views which happens to be a navigation controller into a uipopover. I did have a uibarbutton item on the view im porting with a "done" button to dismiss the navcontroller but I commented out that code and its still appearing, not sure why.

I remember someone mentioning some versions of xcode are wonky with uipopovers anyone know which ones? im using 3.2.3

Answer (score 0):

nevermind I actually had the uibarbutton declared in the viewdidload of the class I was placing in the navcontroller.